# OH-SCM-009: Error When i was migrating from TFS 2013 to VSO

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

We are trying to migrate Source Control (No work items) an On-Prem TFS 2013 project to VS Team Services and getting the following error on 33/3383 ChangeSet/Label.

> OH-SCM-009: Error ocurred while sync, GetAndDownloadFile :TF30063:
>   You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5.
>   [Logs](http://1drv.ms/1l0gCpT)

This happened when i was trying to migrate 1 Team Project (and i was just starting the process).

Log Attached by the way.

[Error Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgR1A.png)

Comment: Has the migration started at all? Most likely the issue can be either caching issue or limited disk space on the TFS Server machine.

Comment: I barely think so.
The project was migrating to a certain point at which no more migrated , the system had 1 file showed that slope, not moving more migration showing me this error in the view of errors.
After that i migrated another team proyect (just code) without any inconvenience

Comment: Hi, Can you try using Visual Studio and doing GetSpecificVersion for changeset 7913 from your on-premises TFS?

Comment: What Exactly do i have to check?
I notive some .pubxml files  but i think thats not the problem? is there an exception for an specific file extension?

Comment: Are you able to download the whole changeset sucessfully?

Comment: @DiegoCastilloCastillo, the log shows that the error message arises when download the "$/Belcorp.PortalConsultoras/Main/Portal.Consultoras.ServiceHost/Portal.Consultoras.ServiceHost.csproj " file. Please first get latest version for it. Additionally, have a check on the logs in the Event Viewer on the TFS AT machine to see whether there are some error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by several reasons:

- Make sure the credentials you use have full access
- Clean TFS cache manually. The cache folder locates at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application
  Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\cache. You may see several folders
  under Team Foundation folder like 4.0, 5.0, clean the cache file in
  all of them.
- Make sure your TFS server disk isn't out of space.
- Check if you are using any proxy

Comment: i'll check but i barely think so.